# Facebook Javascript SDK and Phonegap URL error

Tags: android, facebook-javascript-sdk, cordova

I'm currently trying to develop a facebook login functionality using phonegap in an android app. I've done all the ncessary installs and generated an hash key for the app which I have placed on facebook but I keep getting the following error:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must
>   match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain
>   of one of the App's domains.

I've had a look at the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474122/given-url-is-not-permitted-by-the-application-configuration) link and done what the link suggested but I'm still getting the same error in the logcat console

Comment: are you define your app domain name?

Comment: did you resolve it ?

Comment: @jujule did *you* resolve it? lol

Comment: nope, looks like its not possible :/

Answer (score 0):

The implementation which have you have used will be working for web application (running in browser). For native app, please follow [this steps](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin). Please let me.