# jQuery Date Formatting in Business Catalyst

Tags: javascript, jquery

I work with Business catalyst a lot, and would like to be able to format the dates as desired. Date output is as follows:

```
<span class="date">06-Feb-2014</span>
```

Currently using jQuery 1.10.2, and I can add jQuery UI if that's the way to go.

I have tried the following to no effect:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('span.date').each(function() { 
        var dateFormat = $(this).text()
        var dateFormat = $.datepicker.formatDate('MM dd, yy', new Date(dateFormat));
        //alert(dateFormat);
        $(this).html(dateFormat + "<br>");
    });
});
```

The site in question is http://www.doverfoursquare.org

Perhaps there is some sort of conflict with existing scripts?

Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but it doesn't seem answered...

I would use Liquid for this for example in an events module using a template:

```
{{date | date: "dddd"}}
```

and / or

```
{{date | date: "%d"}} {{date | date: "MMM"}}
```

should get you **"Saturday 4 July"**

You can use this resource to help with the modifiers / filters

http://docs.businesscatalyst.com/dev-assets/reference#!/liquid-reference/reference/filters.html!date-filters

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with formatting dates I always see myself turn back to `momentjs`: http://momentjs.com/ . Its not the fastest framework but it will help you format your date in any desired way:

```
moment().format("DD-MMM-YYYY"); // "20-Feb-2014"
```

Answer (score 0):

It works as intended here:

Note that `datepicker` is extension trough *jQuery UI* and as such you have to include it to work:

> //code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/3wa8a/)

Note that in example the `var dateFormat` is renamed, so to not re-declare existing.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('span.date').each(function() { 
        var value = $(this).text(),
            date = $.datepicker.formatDate(
                'MM dd, yy', new Date(value)
            );
        $(this).html(date + "<br>");
    });
});
```

Or you could say:

```
$(this).html(
    $.datepicker.formatDate(
        'MM dd, yy', new Date($(this).text())
    ) + "<br>"
);
```

---

#### *Edit in regards to date format:*

[Ref. ECMA](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)

Format can be

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

but not

```
DD-MM-YYYY
```

Also [read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

---

#### Errors:

Running you page, it show's this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'player' (index):343

By source that would be:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var settings = {
            progressbarWidth: '200px',
            progressbarHeight: '5px',
            progressbarColor: '#22ccff',
            progressbarBGColor: '#eeeeee',
            defaultVolume: 0.8
        };
        $(".player").player(settings); // <<--- Error line
    });
```

This is a possible source of halting the script at load or the like.

It also gives, (This could be some [Facebook issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14474122/3278057)):

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

The:

> event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

you can ignore as it is a jQuery "thing" and IE fix/hack.

Comment: I've gotten it to "work" and it now affects the dates, but just shows "undefined NaN, NaN", and no proper date. See bottom: [example](http://www.doverfoursquare.org) Any suggestions?

Comment: @user3330323: What if you do a `console.log("DATE:>>" + $(this).text() + "<<")` ? What is the result?

Comment: 'DATE:>><<'

I've got a sample up on [here](http://www.doverfoursquare.org/test.html).

Comment: Well that's curious. It works in safari, but not firefox. Any ideas there?

Comment: @user3330323: Added some more information in answer. You should read up on the date-format as it can easily be gotten wrong. E.g.: `"07 17 2012"` would become Jul 17 2012, `"17 07 2012"` would become May 07 2013, etc. Test in console with e.g. `(new Date("2012 11 11")).toString()`