# Generating Images from profile pictures album in facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

hey guys am trying to fetch the photos that a user have uploaded in the profile pictures album .But the pictures are not fetched correctly .The code is

```
<script>


  function statusChangeCallback(response) {

console.log('statusChangeCallback');
console.log(response);

if (response.status === 'connected') {

  testAPI();
} else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {

  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
    'into this app.';
} else {

  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
    'into Facebook.';
}


}


  function checkLoginState() {

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  statusChangeCallback(response);
});


}

FB.api('/me/albums?fields=id,name', function(response) {


for (var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++) {
var album = response.data[i];
if (album.name == 'Profile Pictures'){

  FB.api('/'+album.id+'/photos', function(photos){
    if (photos && photos.data && photos.data.length){
      for (var j=0; j<photos.data.length; j++){
        var photo = photos.data[j];
        // photo.picture contain the link to picture
        var image = document.createElement('img');
        image.src = photo.picture;


      document.body.appendChild(image);

      }
    }
  });

  break;
}


}

});





  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

  FB.init({
    appId      : '606714542734115',
    cookie     : true,
xfbml      : true,
version    : 'v2.0' 

 };

  (function(d, s, id) {

var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>
```

But when i run this code it shows a blank page ..I know there is errors in my code ..since am new to fb-js-sdk i cant figure it out ..Hope you guys can help me out ..

Comment: _"I know there is errors in my code"_ can you detect & post them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I help you to filled up **html, head, body** tags and **3 missing lines** inside **script** tag:

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {

      console.log('statusChangeCallback');
      console.log(response);

      if (response.status === 'connected') {

          testAPI();
      } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {

          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' + 'into this app.';
      } else {

          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' + 'into Facebook.';
      }

  }

  function checkLoginState() {

      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          statusChangeCallback(response);
      });

  }

function  testAPI() { //####################### 1st missing line

  //############## added count fields
  FB.api('/me/albums?fields=id,name,count', function(response) {


      for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
          var album = response.data[i];
          if (album.name == 'Profile Pictures') {

              //############ debug album total photos
              console.log("you have uploaded " + album.count + " pictures");

              FB.api('/' + album.id + '/photos', function(photos) {
                  if (photos && photos.data && photos.data.length) {
                      for (var j = 0; j < photos.data.length; j++) {
                          var photo = photos.data[j];
                          // photo.picture contain the link to picture
                          var image = document.createElement('img');
                          image.src = photo.picture;


                          document.body.appendChild(image);

                      }
                  }
              });

              break;
          }
      }

  });

} //####################### 2nd missing line

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

      FB.init({
          appId: '606714542734115',
          cookie: true,
          xfbml: true,
          version: 'v2.0'
        }); //####################### 3rd missing line
      };

      (function(d, s, id) {

          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s);
          js.id = id;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>


</head>

<body>
<h1>Testing</h1>
<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hopstarter/button/256/Button-Next-icon.png" alt="Fb Connect" title="Login with facebook" onclick="checkLoginState();"/>
<h1 id="status" onclick="getValue()"></h1>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Also, please ensure your application configuration is correctly setup, [Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474122/given-url-is-not-permitted-by-the-application-configuration)

**Update:**

[image]

**Update (Final working complete code):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<script>
  // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
      // they are logged into this app or not.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
    }
  }

  // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
  // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
  // code below.
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '606714542734115',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.0' // use version 2.0
  });

  // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call 
  // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
  // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
  // the callback you provide.  They can be:
  //
  // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
  // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
  // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
  //    your app or not.
  //
  // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });

  //############## added count fields
   console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information2.... ');
  FB.api('/me/albums?fields=id,name,count', function(response) {
      for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
          console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information3.... ');
          var album = response.data[i];
          if (album.name == 'Profile Pictures') {

              //############ debug album total photos
              document.getElementById('photos_total').innerHTML = "you have uploaded " + album.count + " pictures";
              console.log("you have uploaded " + album.count + " pictures");

              FB.api('/' + album.id + '/photos', function(photos) {
                  if (photos && photos.data && photos.data.length) {
                      for (var j = 0; j < photos.data.length; j++) {
                          var photo = photos.data[j];
                          // photo.picture contain the link to picture
                          var image = document.createElement('img');
                          image.src = photo.picture;


                          document.body.appendChild(image);

                      }
                  }
              });
              break;
          }
      }
  });

  }
</script>

<!--
  Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses
  the JavaScript SDK to present a graphical Login button that triggers
  the FB.login() function when clicked.
-->

<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email,user_photos" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>

<div id="status">
</div>
<div id="photos_total">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```