# MVC 4 Authorization Issue with Facebook

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api, asp.net-mvc-4

Well I have gone through couple of same questions here, however did not able to crack it

My URL Looks like this , localhost:25251/Account/Login

And from the login page , I try to authorize using Facebook, Obviously since my Url pointing to  localhost I got the following error

"**Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.**"

As mentioned in [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289214/how-can-i-use-localhost-while-developing-facebook-graph-website) I changed my Facebook app to point it to test.mydomain.com. Then I tried adding following Host entries.

- ## My IP   test.mydomain.com
- ## localhost   test.mydomain.com

And Even : # localhost:25251 test.mydomain.com,  that too did not work.

Am I missing some stuff..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the same settings for two different domains. If you have a key setup for **test.mydomain.com** and you want to use it for **localhost:25251**, then it will not work. You need to create separate apps for the two domains.

**Facebook API works in localhost** and here's what you need to make sure for the API to work with your localhost:

- Make `localhost` as your **App Domains** in Facebook. App Domains is under the Basic Info
- The **Site URL** should be set to `http://localhost:25251` (in your case). Site URL is under the *Website with Facebook Login* section

Additionaly set the following under the *App on Facebook* section

- **Canvas URL** to `http://localhost:25251/`
- **Secure Canvas URL** to `https://localhost:25251/`

Comment: Thanks Von,  set App Domains and App Domains. Dint see Canvas URl and Secure Canvas URl.

Comment: Read my answer again, it's under **App on Facebook**, you need to click that item.  It's in the section called "Select how your app integrates with Facebook" just below the "Basic Info" section.